# When using NGRX with Angular SSR, the initial load of the page doesn't show async HTML

Tags: angular, seo, ngrx, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I've been trying a good amount of time now but I can't seem to wrap my head around this, I'm using Angular Universal to serve this SSR project. In order to make my product page crawlable, I have to have product information available in the first DOC fetch. Since I'm using NGRX to load data asynchronously, this requires a bit of extra work (but I'm not sure if my thinking is correct).

So for example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="storeData$ | async as data">
    <h1 [innerHtml]="data.name"></h1>
    <p [innerHtml]="data.description"></p>
</ng-container>
```

When resolving this page I've tried 2 different route guards.

*1st route guard:*

Go through my normal chain of NGRX effects and resolving the navigation when data is present in the store. This chain of effects includes getting product information via GraphQL, calculating prices, getting filter options and other custom objects we need in order to build the page. I've checked the ngOnInit, this always fires after the resolve is done, so there is no timing issue here (it seems). But nothing shows up in the initial DOC, even when there's just static content outside of the async ng-container this won't show up in the initial load either.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const getPayload = {
      categorySlug: route.params['subcategorySlug'],
      productGroupSlug: route.params['productGroupSlug'],
      productSlug: route.params['productSlug'],
      locale: this.locale,
      setFilters: []
    };

    return this.getProductQueryResult(getPayload).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        console.log('RESOLVE!');
        return of(true);
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        console.log('CATCH!');
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }

  private getProductQueryResult(getPayload: any) {
    return this._store.select('FilterPage', 'Loaded', 'ProductPage', 'queryResult').pipe(
      tap(data => this.prefetch(data, getPayload)),
      filter(data => !!data),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  private prefetch(queryResult, getPayload) {
    if (!queryResult) {
      this._store.dispatch(filterActions.initProduct(getPayload));
    }
  }
```

*2nd route guard:*

Only get the essential product information via an HTTP get call, toPromise(), then store in NGRX, resolve the page, async load data (see html snippet) from NGRX. This DOES work.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      const productSlug = route.params['productSlug'];
      const predicate = `masterData(current(slug(${this.locale}%3D%22${productSlug}%22)))`;
      const url = environment.commercetoolsURL + '/' + environment.commercetoolsProjectKey + '/products?where=' + predicate;

      this.http.get(url).toPromise().then((res: any) => {
        this._store.dispatch(filterActions.setProductPrerenderData({data: res.results[0]}));
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
  }
```

I **could** use the 2nd option for creating a prerender for the page but that would mean that I have to fetch the product information twice: once for the prerender, and once for the async page view, which is not ideal.

A few of my findings:

1. **No route guard** doesn't work. Only static HTML gets loaded in the initial DOC.
2. **Route guard with NGRX** doesn't work. Nothing gets loaded in the initial DOC.
3. **Route guard with HTTP GET** works, but other essential information, included in the NGRX effects won't get fetched, need an extra call for that.

The most important question I have is. Why doesn't it work when the page is resolved when the store data is loaded, and served on the page instantly?

Comment: Have you tried with `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` on `RouterModule.forRoot`?

Comment: Our project is in Angular 14 and I have `initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking'`